# After pre-commit hook: git add makes staged files disappear

Tags: r, git, githooks, r-styler

I'm trying to setup a local pre-commit hook. It should check if any edited files are styled according to the tidyverse styleguide (using [styler](https://styler.r-lib.org/index.html)). Because my company does not allow for direct access to github, I cannot use [precommit](https://lorenzwalthert.github.io/precommit/articles/available-hooks.html#style-files-1), and have to setup the hook by editing the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file.

## Setup

This is what I tried: My `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eo pipefail

CHANGED_FILES=$(git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR)

get_pattern_files() {
    pattern=$(echo "$*" | sed "s/ /\$\\\|/g")
    echo "$CHANGED_FILES" | { grep "$pattern$" || true; }
}

R_FILES=$(get_pattern_files .R)

# if R_FILES is not empty, run Rscript
if [[ -n "$R_FILES" ]]
then
    Rscript ./style.R $R_FILES
fi

# exit with 1, if Rscript failed
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

and my `./style.R`

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
output <- styler::style_file(path = args)
if (any(output$changed) == TRUE) {quit(status = 1)}
```

## Problem

When I edit a file, I can see it in the diff.

```
user@machine:~/r_template$ git diff
diff --git a/src/main.R b/src/main.R
index 8d2f097..dd1272d 100644
--- a/src/main.R
+++ b/src/main.R
@@ -1 +1 @@
-1 + 1
+1 +1           <-- this is what I have changed in the file
```

I add it with `git add -u` and then git commit. The hook gets called, and aborts the commit (because the Rscript exits with status 1) as expected.

```
user@machine:~/r_template$ git commit
Styling  1  files:
 src/main.R ℹ
────────────────────────────────────────
Status  Count   Legend
✓       0       File unchanged.
ℹ       1       File changed.
x       0       Styling threw an error.
────────────────────────────────────────
Please review the changes carefully!
```

and can see an (expected) edited file

```
user@machine:~/r_template$ git status
On branch feature/precommit-hooks
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   src/main.R

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   src/main.R
```

with the intended changes done by `styler::style_file()`

```
user@machine:~/r_template$ git diff
diff --git a/src/main.R b/src/main.R
index dd1272d..8d2f097 100644
--- a/src/main.R
+++ b/src/main.R
@@ -1 +1 @@
-1 +1
+1 + 1       <-- this is done by styler::style_file()
```

Ok, so next I want to stage this edit, so I `git add -u`. But then something happens I cannot understand

```
utxkanal@vlx00950:~/r_template$ git status
On branch feature/precommit-hooks
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

The staging area is completely empty. And still, the change in `src/main.R` is in effect.
What is happening here?

Comment: fwiw you can use `pre-commit` without needing to use github via `repo: local` -- it also smooths over exactly this problem

Comment: to explain your behaviour: your original staged changed is only a misformatting -- when you stage the formatting it just resets it back to the contents that are already committed (no difference to `HEAD`)

Comment: @AnthonySottile since the question was "what is happening here" I feel like your second comment could be posted as an answer that can be accepted since that is exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to understanding what's going on is this: *The staging area is never empty, and never contains any changes.*  To which the obvious reply is *what the f—, you obviously don't know what you're talking about* because `git status` shows an empty staging area and `git diff` shows changes.  And yes, they do.  The trick is that *these are strategically developed lies*.

[As Emily Dickinson's poem *Tell all the Truth but tell it slant* points out](https://interestingliterature.com/2016/11/a-short-analysis-of-emily-dickinsons-tell-all-the-truth-but-tell-it-slant/), trying to instantly see the whole picture all at once is overwhelming.  The whole truth of Git's index / staging-area is that it contains a *full copy of every file, ready to be committed*.  That is, there are at all times *three* copies of the current commit:

- There's the frozen-for-all-time one *in* the current commit itself.  This is what you started with.
- There's an "in between" version, which I put here because it's "between", but don't describe yet.
- There's a *usable* (edit-able, view-able, and generally useful for doing work) copy, in your working tree.  This is how you get stuff done.

The "in-between" version is simply a full copy of every file *in Git's staging area*, which Git also calls *the index*.

When `git diff` or `git diff --cached` shows *changes*, what Git is doing is playing the [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference) game with two *snapshots*.  There are two full pictures, but the two have some differences.  Git *omits*, from a diff output, *all the stuff that is the same*, because that stuff is boring!  We want to know what's *different*.

The same thing happens with `git status`, except that instead of showing us what's different, it tells us which *file names* have *one or more differences*.  So this:

```
user@machine:~/r_template$ git status
On branch feature/precommit-hooks
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   src/main.R
```

means that when Git compares the *full snapshot of every file* in the `HEAD` (current) commit to the *full snapshot of every file in the staging area*, one file is different: `src/main.R`.  Meanwhile, this second part:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   src/main.R
```

means that when Git (separately) compares the *full snapshot in the staging area* to the *full snapshot in your working tree*, one file is different: `src/main.R` (again).

If we now change the *index* (aka staging) copy of `src/main.R`—we're allowed to replace it wholesale at any time, and formatting hooks do that sort of trick—then the difference from `HEAD`-to-index changes.  Perhaps it even disappears entirely!  And, separately, the difference from index-to-working-tree changes as well.

In this particular case, what happened is that the frozen, archived, `HEAD` copy and the working tree copy *already matched*.  Only the index/staging-area copy was different.  Running `git add src/main.R` told Git: *replace the index copy with the working tree copy*.  It did that, and now all three copies matched again.

**Footnote:** "The staging area is never empty, and never contains any changes" is obviously an overstatement.  It's also *wrong* because it *is* possible to have a completely-empty staging area, by removing every file from it.  It's just not *normal* to do that.  The only time you normally have that is in a fresh, new, totally-empty repository, when you're working on your first commit.  But it's still a good way to remember that the index / staging-area has a *full snapshot* of every file.  In fact, the point of this is that the full snapshot *in* the index area is, in effect, the snapshot you're proposing to put into your *next* commit.

(There's also the *much trickier* case of multiple index / staging-areas.)